# Haskell - How to make "div" or "/" simply in Instance?

Tags: haskell

Example

```
    data SomeData = Number Integer | String String | Bool Bool
                  deriving Eq
```

And,I want to use 'div' with SomeData.

```
    instance Num SomeData where
            (Number x) + (Number y) = Number $ x + y -- It's Ok.
            (Number x) - (Number y) = Number $ x - y -- It's Ok.
            (Number x) * (Number y) = Number $ x * y -- It's ok.
    instance Integral SomeData Where
            (Number x) `div` (Number y) = Number $ x `div` y
```

But I got Error Message.

```
main.hs:105:10:
    No instance for (Real SomeData)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Real SomeData)
    In the instance declaration for `Integral SomeData'

main.hs:105:10:
    No instance for (Enum SomeData)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Enum SomeData)
    In the instance declaration for `Integral SomeData'
```

Ok,If I want to use `div` with SomeData data,should I write `Real Instance` and `Enum Instance` for SomeData step-by-step? Or Is there another good way ?

Comment: Isn't the issue that div returns a Real and you don't have a type constructor in SomeData for Number Real?

Comment: @Paolo No. `div :: Integral a -> a -> a -> a`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to write instances for `Real` and `Enum`.  You can cheat by doing

```
instance Real SomeData
instance Enum SomeData
```

Then you will get runtime failures if you use the methods in those classes.
Or, for `Real`:

```
instance Real SomeData where
    toRational (Number i) = toRational i
```

(You have a lot of partial functions already, so I assume you don't mind some more.)

Answer (score 2):

A general method to solve problems like this is to use `:info` command in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  quot :: a -> a -> a
  rem :: a -> a -> a
  div :: a -> a -> a
  mod :: a -> a -> a
  quotRem :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  divMod :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  toInteger :: a -> Integer
```

So no, you cannot implement `Integral` without implementing `Real`. You could have started straight from `div`:

```
Prelude> :i div
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  ...
  div :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in GHC.Real
infixl 7 div
```

So you can see that `div` is a method of Integral type class and you need `Real` and `Enum` to be defined as well. If you check `Real`, it requires `Num` and `Ord` etc.