# How choose which classes to make an instance of when overloading operators in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to overload the basic math operators (+,-,*,/, negate) and ordering operators (<,>, >=, <=, ==) for the made up data type Pair. Currently, I have an instance of num which requires me to overload its visible members, but I am having hard time figuring out if I need to make multiple instances of different classes like Fractional, Ord, and so forth, or if there is a better method to overload these specific operators.

Code Example:

```
 data Pair = Pair (Int, Int) deriving (Eq, Show)
 instance Num Pair where
    Pair (a,b) + Pair (c,d) = Pair (a+c,b+d)
    Pair (a,b) * Pair (c,d) = Pair (a*c,b*d)
    Pair (a,b) - Pair (c,d) = Pair (a-c,b-d)
    Pair (a,b) / Pair (c,d) = Pair  (a/c , b/d) // throws an error for this line.
    abs    (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (abs a,    abs b) 
    signum (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (signum a, signum b) 
    fromInteger i = Pair (fromInteger i, fromInteger i)
```

Comment: `(/)` is part of `Fractional`, not `Num`. I'm having a rather hard time to decipher your question, tbh.

Comment: @Zeta I altered the text to make it clearer, but I am starting to think this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154722/haskell-how-to-make-div-or-simply-in-instance?rq=1  or at least similar to it.

Comment: if in doubt just open up GHCi and ask (for example `:i (/)` it will tell you what class to implement

Comment: OT: you know that you will have a hard time making the ordering compatible with your addition/multiplication? (meaning you will not get an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring))

Comment: @Carsten No, I didn't know I am just starting to learn haskell so there are quite a few elements I don't know about it yet. If you have a reference that I can read to ensure I get an ordered ring and I will definitely do so.

Comment: @user5960886 it's not really a Haskell thing (that's why I did put the **O**ff**T**opic there) - it's a math problem - if you define your operations element-wise then `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` will be the additive and multiplicative identities and both `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` will be `> (0,0)` - but as in an ordered list you have `a > b, c > 0 => a*c > b*c` you run into trouble with this: (example `(1,0) > (0,1)` but `(1,0) * (0,1) = (0,0)`, `(0,1) * (0,1) = (0,1)` and `(0,0) < (0,1)`)

Comment: @user5960886 you probably don't have to care but I found it strange that you want to implement *Ord* + *Num*  as I had the feeling you wanted to do math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Some preliminary ranting

Generally in Haskell, you should avoid thinking of “overloading an operator”. Type classes are more than syntax for overloading operators; rather think of them as *abstract axiomatisations of data types*. Now if that sounds scary forget the word axiom and consider an example.

A *number type* `N` is a type whose values `a`, `b`, `c`... fulfill properties (*laws*) such as

```
a + 0 = a
a * 1 = a
a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c
abs a * signum a = a
```

It is properties like these which allow you to truely write num-polymorphic code (i.e. that'll work with *any* numerical type) and still be certain that you'll get meaningful results in the end for all of them. That really is the power of overloading. Just being able to re-use a nice short identifier such as `+` may be handy in itself, but really wouldn't gain you much over custom operators like `+.` for specialised num types (that's [how O'Caml does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017172/why-is-ocamls-not-polymorphic)).

Now, for such laws to be formulable, you need to have *all* these operators available, and that's why we have classes which require us to not just overload whichever operator we fancy right now, but a whole coherent group of them.

### Start reading here if you haven't already...

Classes aren't some special built-in magic. You can easily define your own classes<sup>†</sup>, or, for standard classes like `Num`, look up where they're defined. The easiest way to find class definitions (or any other library declarations) is the [Hayoo seatch engine](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%2B). It will for e.g. `+` guide you right away to [the `(+) :: a -> a -> a` Class Method on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-). There you see how `+` is contained in

```
class  Num a  where
    {-# MINIMAL (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) #-}
    (+), (-), (*)       :: a -> a -> a
    negate              :: a -> a
    abs                 :: a -> a
    signum              :: a -> a
    fromInteger         :: Integer -> a
```

So if you want to overload the `+` operator you'll need to define all<sup>‡</sup> of `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, `negate`, `abs`, `signum` and `fromInteger`.

### Whoa, but maybe you didn't even want something like `abs`!

Very reasonable. But then your type is evidently not really a number type! IMO you shouldn't make anything a `Num` instance that's not just a representation of a single number. Note that there are simpler classes available: you probably want [AdditiveGroup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html)

```
class AdditiveGroup v where
  zeroV :: v
  (^+^) :: v -> v -> v
  negateV :: v -> v
  (^-^) :: v -> v -> v
```

This is a class for more general *vector spaces*. You can easily make your type an instance:

```
instance AdditiveGroup Pair where
  zeroV = Pair (0,0)
  Pair (a,b) ^+^ Pair (c,d) = Pair (a+c, b+d)
  Pair (a,b) ^-^ Pair (c,d) = Pair (a-c, b-d)
  negateV (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (-a ,-b)
```

You notice that this class doesn't have a multiplication. Well, it turns out that mathematically, multiplication doesn't really make all that much sense on tuples. There are *other* kind of multiplications though (scalar multiplications) that make sense on vector spaces. Browse the [documentation of the vector-space package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2).

### On a different note

Also consider whether you even need AdditiveGroup instance. Daniel Wagner uses [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878962/745903) a class that's way more general than numbers, and can be used for all kinds of container-types. Argumably, your `Pair` is more of a *container for numbers*, than a number per se. Therefore, I recommend only implementing

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (f y)
instance Applicative Pair where
    pure v = Pair v v
    Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)
```

`Functor` is really simple: it allows you to apply a function to all elements in a container. `Applicative` basically allows you to cross-apply functions between two containers.

With these instances you can, instead of using numerical operators directly, add pairs by writing `liftA2 (+) (Pair 1 2) (Pair 3 4)` whenever you need that operation. A bit more verbose, but also a good deal more explicit!

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Frankly, it's better not to do that too often though. Classes as I said are meant to represent deep mathematical axiomatisations; this is not possible for anything that *OO programmers* would write a class for. Nor is it necessary to write custom classes all the time: `data` alone can get you pretty far in a functional language.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Actually it's sufficient to implement *either* `(-)` *or* `negate`. That's what the `MINIMAL` pragma tells you.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd probably write something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Control.Applicative

data Pair a = Pair a a deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Functor)
instance Applicative Pair where
    pure v = Pair v v
    Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)

instance Num a => Num (Pair a) where
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    (-) = liftA2 (-)
    (*) = liftA2 (*)
    negate = liftA negate
    abs    = liftA abs
    signum = liftA signum
    fromInteger = pure . fromInteger

instance Fractional a => Fractional (Pair a) where
    (/) = liftA2 (/)
    recip = liftA recip
    fromRational = pure . fromRational
```

You can learn which class a particular operation is related to by looking at its type:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

Hence if you want to support `(/)`, you should look into implementing the `Fractional` class.

Comment: This kind of misses the question given in the title. It's not about overloading, but how user59...whatshisname can find out _which_ instance needs to be written. You can still copy Carsten's comment, though.

Comment: @Zeta Okay, I've addressed that portion of the question now I think. Thanks for pointing out that I had missed that concern.